# Call stored procedure within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure within SQL Server 2008. Inside this SP, I need to call another one and pass in two parameters as shown here:
This gets executed at the end of the parent SP

```
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId, @RequestedById
```

This SP looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [Testing].[InsertNewValues]
@UserId int,
@RequestedById int
 AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Do something with two parameters

END
```

Yet when I run my project I get the error:

> Additional information: Procedure or function 'InsertNewValues'
>   expects parameter '@RequestedById', which was not supplied.

I've tried

```
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues](@UserId, @RequestedById)
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId @RequestedById
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] (@UserId, @RequestedById)
```

But with no luck, can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: I don't believe you.  I think the stored procedure takes more than two parameters.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I takes two? as shown in my question? unless I'm being daft ?

Comment: . . You would get that error if a third argument, called `@RequestBYId` were needed by the stored procedure.  The SP doesn't care what the variable is called.  So, something strange is going on.

Comment: fyi I was able to fool myself into believing I had a similar error, but only by executing a similarly named parent procedure and not supplying values to the parent procedure.   I got so focused on why the child procedure "wasn't" running - didn't even notice the parent procedure was the issue.  I'm confessing my mistake, just in case it's any help.

Comment: please show us the code of the line that is getting the error.

Answer (score 1):

You can call any number of SP's from one SP (further you can extend this to other SP - nested). You can also call functions from your SP. But from your code, calling line and error.. All are indicating that you are not calling your SP properly and you are clearly missing parameter separator. This may be a typo.

You have missed a `,` between your parameters.

Change `EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId @RequestedById`

to

```
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId, @RequestedById
```

Answer (score 0):

From

```
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues](@UserId, @RequestedById)
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId @RequestedById
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] (@UserId, @RequestedById)
```

To

```
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId, @RequestedById
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId, @RequestedById -- missing comma here
EXEC [Testing].[InsertNewValues] @UserId, @RequestedById
```

please try, I think I may not need to know why its 3 times..my assumptions is you might be testing your validation with duplicates.